# Retrieve keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, enter

I'm implementing keypress to submit when enter is pressed. I made a jquery plugin and I need some help:

```
jQuery.fn.enterPress = function(obj, button) {          
            if (e.which == 13) {
                jQuery(button).click();

            }           
    };
```

In this function, I retrieve obj( html form), and button (which one will be clicked).

I'm not sure, but I probably don't need this "obj". 
My problem is that I don't have this 'e'. I tried a lot of ways, but I don't know how could I retrive it.

I have made this:

```
jQuery('#' + obj.id).keypress(function(e) {}
```

But the function was fired twice, sometimes three times.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery already has a `keypress` method, you could just use it. Is there a reason you're developing your own?

Comment: Actually, I wanted something more general. Like passing attributes (in my case, the button id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a built in method for this called keypress.

```
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     // do stuff here 
  }
}
```

If you want to add a more generic method for binding an 'enter' keypress event to a jQuery object and then clicking a button (as you mentioned in your question and comment), you could do something like this:

```
var $button = jQuery('#somebutton');

jQuery.fn.enterPress = function(callback) {
    jQuery(this).keypress(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 13 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            callback();
        }
    });
};

$button.click(function(){
    alert('button was clicked');
})

jQuery('#target').enterPress(function() {
    // what you want to happen after enter is pressed
    $button.click();
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XNKsq/)

Comment: Hello @Cody, I tried your answer, the preventdefault didn't worked. he button is not clicked.
also, I tried isPreventDefault() and always come 'false'.

Also, I tried e.stopPropagation(), it worked, but fires only on second hit of enter (if the pages is loaded with focus in the field and I press enter).

I put an alert inside the Jquery.fn.enterPress and always fired, but the obj.keypress... only on second hit.

Comment: Hey @viictoorh, I've updated my answer along with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XNKsq/

Comment: Thanks @Cody. It worked. I'll just make some modifications for my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

This code sends a form when clicks "13 keyCode" == "Enter"

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
           $("#myFOrm").submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `return` key is already bound to submit HTML forms, but here's how you listen for a keypress event using various methods anyway:

**Regular JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('yourFormId').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
        document.getElementById('yourButtonId').click();
}, false);
```

**Also regular JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('yourFormId').onkeypress = function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13)
        document.getElementById('yourButtonId').click();
};
```

**Or jQuery:**

```
$('yourFormId').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which === 13)
        $('yourButtonId').trigger('click');
});
```